# Algorithm that Groups so that sum is close to target value

Tags: algorithm, math

I am trying to find an algorithm, but googling my exact problem is not finding the exact result I need.

I am given a set of numbers and a target sum. I need to assign the numbers to groups so that the sum of those groups is as close as possible without going over the target value.

```
Example Target Sum = 99
Example Set = { 70, 40, 10, 70, 98, 14, 4, 7, 29, 11, 91, 50, 30 }
```

Desired Results would be something like:

```
{ 70, 29 } 
{ 40, 50, 7} 
{ 98 } 
{ 91, 4 }
{ 70, 10, 11 } 
{ 30, 14 }
```

...because they all add up to a number close to 99.

**The goal will be to have as few groups as possible.** 
I don't need to worry much about resources. It will be executed sparingly, and the number of values will be pretty low.

Comment: Can you clarify what does close mean? Do you want the sum of the differences between the groups and the target to be minimized or do you want the least number of groups that are off the target, or some balance between the two?

Comment: I remember I solved a similar problem long time ago using [dynamic programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming) It's quite hard to grasp the concept though.

Comment: The sum of that first example group is 99 (70 + 29). Which is exact. The sum of the second group is 97, which is close to 99....It doesn't really matter how close they are. The point is that I need to smallest number of groups possible.

Comment: If the objective is to, say, minimize the difference between the smallest and the largest set, it is a generalization of the [partition problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem) which is known to be NP-complete.

Comment: The objective is to have the smallest number of groups possible where each group's sum doesn't go over the target value.

Comment: Ok, so it is infeasible for a group to have a larger total value than the target sum?

Comment: Right. That's the only rule. The groups sum cannot go over the target value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the objective is to minimize the number of groups and the only constraint is that the total size of each group may not exceed the target value, the problem under consideration is the [bin packing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem) problem, an [NP-hard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-hardness) optimization problem which is relatively well understood.

Generally speaking, relatively simple heuristics called First Fit or First Fit Decreasing yield approximation ratios smaller than 2. More precisely, First Fit Decreasing yields a tight ratio of `(11/9)OPT+(6/9)`. Bin packing does not admit a PTAS (and, consequently, no FPTAS), but an asymptotic PTAS with ratio `(1+epsilon)OPT+1` where `epsilon` is the accuracy parameter.

If a decent solution with a relatively easy implementation is needed, First Fit Decreasing might be a candidate.