# Trim a List so the Sum is Close to a Target Value

Tags: python, numpy

I have a list of values that add up to a number and I need to trim it so the sum is close to a target value. Is there any standard algorithm for this? I will elaborate below:

Assume there is a class named `MyClass` and `obj_list` is a list containing instances of `MyClass`. Each instance has a property named `area`. I can calculate the total area as:

`tot_area = numpy.sum([i.area for i in obj_list])`

But I need to make sure that total area is close to (a little above/below) a value `target_area`. I cannot modify how the instances of `MyClass` are generated as this includes drawing from meaningful measurements and some randomization. However, I control how many there are (`num_objs`) and I can remove instances from `obj_list`. My goal is to remove the smallest number of instances.

My idea is to remove the instances with the smallest area and then work my way up, but this has some drawbacks. For example, what if removing only the third biggest instance is enough to achieve the objective?

I wonder if there are better ways to do this. Any help, suggestion, or name of algorithms is appreciated.

Comment: It sounds like another way to ask your question is "what is the subset of my list that has the closest sum to a target value?"

Here is a post answering this question.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66289989/given-an-array-of-integers-find-the-subset-sum-closest-to-k

Comment: Thank you for your comment. It lead me to the concept of the Knapsack Problem and I solved my challenge. I will post an answer to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the [comment by @JRose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77587572#comment136782623_77587572) and [an answer to a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41876552/7180705), I found out that this is an example of [the Knapsack Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem). The idea is than a number of objects with different values and sizes need to be packed into a knapsack so as to maximize the total value while meeting the size limitation.

In my example, all instances of `MyClass` have the same value, but have different sizes (refereed to as area). I found a working example in [SciPy docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/tutorial/optimize.html#knapsack-problem-example) and added some modifications, including a softer boundary for the target area. In the end, this satisfied my requirements.

The code is as follows:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import optimize
from scipy.optimize import milp

sizes = np.array([0.003968, 0.0148, 0.022912, 0.024832, 0.02912, 0.032448,
                  0.034176, 0.035136, 0.035584, 0.049344, 0.057984, 0.059904,
                  0.063744, 0.080064, 0.085824])  # tot_area = 0.62984
target_area = 0.45
pct_error = 0.03  # Acceptable error as percentage of target_area.

# All instances of MyClass have equal value.
values = np.full_like(sizes, 1.0)

# Set decision variable (x_i) to be between 0 and 1 and to be integers.
# This makes them effectively Boolean, and they can be cast to bool in the end.
integrality = np.full_like(values, True)  # x_i must be integers within bounds.
bounds = optimize.Bounds(0, 1)  # x_i must be between 0 and 1.

# Calculate and set the upper and lower bounds.
lb = (1 - pct_error) * target_area
ub = (1 + pct_error) * target_area
constraints = optimize.LinearConstraint(A=sizes, lb=lb, ub=ub)

optimization_result = milp(c=-values, constraints=constraints,
                           integrality=integrality, bounds=bounds)

if not optimization_result.success:
    raise RuntimeError('The MILP optimization procedure failed!')

print(f'Total area: {sizes[optimization_result.x.astype(bool)].sum()}' )
#  0.45998399999999995

print(optimization_result.x)
# array([0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0.])

print( sizes[optimization_result.x.astype(bool)] )
# [0.0148 0.022912 0.024832 0.02912 0.032448 0.034176 0.035136 0.035584 0.049344 0.057984 0.059904 0.063744]
```